# Forwarding a domain name

Tags: dns

I am trying to forward a domain name with the .app extension to a domain name with the extension .com. So far I have not been successful. Upon some further research into domain name forwarding and extensions, I came across posts and articles stating that domain name forwarding is not supported for domain names with the .app extension - due to their requirement for https/specific SSL certificates.

My question is: is there something I'm missing/some tip/trick that should be used to/when forwarding from a .app domain.

Thank you

Comment: For an HTTP redirects, all the names are the same and all will work, as long as you have the certificate for that name under HTTPS. Other than that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. Your DNS provider or webhoster should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your domain host, you might be able to insert a "domain alias." I don't know for sure if this will work...

Search (google) with this phrase:

"creating a domain alias {Your_Domain_Host_Name}"